# macOS Key Event Slow Repeat

Tags: macos, keyboard, nsevent, macos-high-sierra

I'm trying to create a small WASD demo game in macOS. I'm using `NSEvent` for handling the key events. To detect the key presses, I'm searching for `keyDown` events. Here's what I have:

```swift
    NSEvent.addLocalMonitorForEvents(matching: .keyDown) {
        (keyEvent) -> NSEvent? in
        if self.keyDown(with: keyEvent) {
            return nil
        } else {
            return keyEvent
        }
    }

func keyDown(with event: NSEvent) -> Bool {
    
    userInt.keyDown(key: event.characters)

    return true
}
```

So here, I'm holding the keys down (as you'd expect in a game), and I'm getting some very slow movement. Like, when I'm holding it down, it's very janky. Upon further inspection, I saw that the key repeat interval was 0.1s, which was set in my system preferences. This means that it's skipping frames. However, in a game, I don't want this setting to affect the movement. So how can I detect a key holding event *without* being held up by the key repeat interval?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should ignore key-repeat events (with `isARepeat` true). Instead, when you get a key-down event, start a timer that fires however often you want to advance your game state. Advance the game state in that timer's firing code. When you get a key-up event, stop the timer.

Comment: I actually had that technique in mind, but I thought there would be a simpler way which wasn't in the NSEvent documentation. But if that's the only method, I'll go for it. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. While you're at it, you should probably be basing your action on the event's key code, not the characters. For example, you want to "move forward" for the key that's second from the left in the top row of letters, not necessarily the one which produces the "w" character, which might be in a different location with a different keyboard layout. That key has `keyCode` `kVK_ANSI_W`, regardless of what letter the keyboard layout produces.